# Week number for each quarter

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I have a column of dates whose week number I want to extract, but the week numbers should reset every quarter for 4 quarters.

The issue is that every week should start from monday to sunday and the code should only consider the dates in each week which are between these days, what I mean is for example, 01-01-2021 till 03-01-2021 should be in week 1, 04-01-2021 to 10-01-2021 should be in week 2 and so on.

If anyone can help with this it would be great.

Comment: did you try anything? btw. "*01-01-2021 till 03-01-2021 should be in week 1*" means writing your own week numbering system I think since these dates are in ISO week 53 of 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function do what you want.

```
import datetime

date = [2015, 3, 1]

def get_week(date):
    year = date[0]
    month = date[1]
    day = date[2]
    global_week_numner = datetime.date(year,month,day).isocalendar()[1]
    week_nums_each_quarter = 13
    current_quarter = ( (month-1)//3 + 1)
    local_week_numner = global_week_numner - (week_nums_each_quarter * (current_quarter - 1))
    return local_week_numner
    
print (get_week(date))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this almost gives me the answer.

Does your code assume every quarter will have 13 weeks?